GridToolbar Filter button MUI
i want to implement some custom logic for Grid Filter panel when filter applied can any one help me for this , i have used GridToolbarFilterButton for grid filter panel , now i need to update the filter model on filter changes how i can do  ??,need to customize the filtermodel on filterchange if field has no value then don't need to consider , i have already created some other functionality that conncting the filtermodel where i passed some default items for filter that shows in slide in show when ever i am applying filter from filter panel it will consider all rows on filter changes which have no values
i want to extend on filter change functionality of Grid filter panel how to do ?

Please provide a code sample or a codesandbox so the problem is understandable.
